# Enum values are not shown properly in generated wsdl file. Why?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, wsdl

I am trying to find out how WSDL is generated when I'm opening link like "myservice.com/myservice.svc?singleWsdl". The problem is that I have language enum in  my code and some values are missing from wsdl file. If do like this:

```
    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Hebrew = 73

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Hiri_Motu = 75

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Croatian = 76

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Haitian = 77
```

Then I've got this in generated WSDL file:

```
<xs:enumeration value="Hebrew">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:appinfo>
<EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">73</EnumerationValue>
</xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:enumeration>
<xs:enumeration value="Hiri_Motu"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Croatian"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Haitian"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Hungarian"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Armenian"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Herero"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Interlingua"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Indonesian"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Interlingue"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Igbo"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Sichuan_Yi"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Inupiaq"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Ilocano"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Ido"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Icelandic"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Inuktitut"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Javanese"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Georgian"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Kongo"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Kikuyu"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Kuanyama"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Kazakh"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Kalaallisut"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Central_Khmer"/>
<xs:enumeration value="NA"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Kannada"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Kanuri"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Kashmiri"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Kurdish"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Komi"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Cornish"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Kirghiz"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Lao"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Latin"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Luxembourgish"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Ganda"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Limburgan"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Lingala"/>
<xs:enumeration value="Luba_Katanga">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:appinfo>
<EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">114</EnumerationValue>
</xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:enumeration>
```

So a lot of languages miss their EnumerationValue. I was able to find out that this problem occurs because of missing "74" value. I don't want either insert some dummy value or shift all the values after "73", maybe any ideas how can I fix it?

PS:
this works fine:

```
 <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
        Hebrew = 73

        <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
        Hiri_Motu = 74

        <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
        Croatian = 75

        <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
        Haitian = 76
```

Result:

```
<xs:enumeration value="Hebrew">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:appinfo>
<EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">73</EnumerationValue>
</xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:enumeration>
<xs:enumeration value="Hiri_Motu">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:appinfo>
<EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">74</EnumerationValue>
</xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:enumeration>
<xs:enumeration value="Croatian">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:appinfo>
<EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">75</EnumerationValue>
</xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:enumeration>
<xs:enumeration value="Haitian">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:appinfo>
<EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">76</EnumerationValue>
</xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:enumeration>
```

Full enum:

```
  <System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "3.0.0.0"),  _
     System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name:="Language",     [Namespace]:="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Greenway.PrimeSuite.DataContracts.Person")>  _
Public Enum Language As Integer

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    LookUp = 9999

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Unknown = 0

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    English = 1

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Spanish = 2

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    French = 3

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Japanese = 4

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Chinese = 5

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Vietnamese = 6

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Russian = 7

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Arabic = 8

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Filipino = 9

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    German = 10

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Greek = 11

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Hindi = 12

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Italian = 13

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Korean = 14

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Polish = 15

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Portuguese = 16

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Other = 17

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Declined = 18

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Somali = 19

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Hmong = 20

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Lithuanian = 21

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Afrikaans = 22

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    American_Indian = 23

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Akan = 24

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Amharic = 25

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Aragonese = 26

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Assamese = 27

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Avaric = 28

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Aymara = 29

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Azerbaijani = 30

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Bashkir = 31

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Belarusian = 32

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Bulgarian = 33

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Bihari_languages = 34

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Bislama = 35

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Bambara = 36

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Bengali = 37

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Tibetan = 38

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Breton = 39

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Bosnian = 40

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Cambodian = 41

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Catalan = 42

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Chechen = 43

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Chamorro = 44

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Cantonese = 45

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Corsican = 46

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Cree = 47

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Church_Slavic = 48

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Chuvash = 49

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Welsh = 50

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Czech = 51

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Danish = 52

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Dutch = 53

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Divehi = 54

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Dzongkha = 55

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Ewe = 56

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Esperanto = 57

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Estonian = 58

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Basque = 59

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Faroese = 60

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Persian = 61

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Fulah = 62

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Finnish = 63

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Fijian = 64

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Western_Frisian = 65

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Irish = 66

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Gaelic = 67

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Galician = 68

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Guarani = 69

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Gujarati = 70

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Manx = 71

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    Hausa = 72

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Hebrew = 73

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Hiri_Motu = 75

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Croatian = 76

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Haitian = 77

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Hungarian = 78

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Armenian = 79

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Herero = 80

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Interlingua = 81

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Indonesian = 82

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Interlingue = 83

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Igbo = 84

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Sichuan_Yi = 85

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Inupiaq = 86

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Ilocano = 87

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Ido = 88

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Icelandic = 89

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Inuktitut = 90

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Javanese = 91

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Georgian = 92

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Kongo = 93

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Kikuyu = 94

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Kuanyama = 95

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Kazakh = 96

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Kalaallisut = 97

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Central_Khmer = 98

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    NA = 99

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Kannada = 100

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Kanuri = 101

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Kashmiri = 102

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Kurdish = 103

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Komi = 104

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Cornish = 105

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Kirghiz = 106

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Lao = 107

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Latin = 108

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Luxembourgish = 109

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Ganda = 110

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Limburgan = 111

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Lingala = 112

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Luba_Katanga = 114

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Latvian = 115

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Mandarin = 116

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Malagasy = 117

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Marshallese = 118

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Mien = 119

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Macedonian = 120

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Malayalam = 121

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Mongolian = 122

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Marathi = 123

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Maori = 124

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Malay = 125

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Maltese = 126

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Burmese = 127

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Nauru = 128

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Norwegian_Bokmål = 129

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Ndebele_North = 130

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Nepali = 131

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Ndonga = 132

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Norwegian_Nynorsk = 133

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Norwegian = 134

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Ndebele_South = 135

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Navajo = 136

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Chichewa_Chewa_Nyanja = 137

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Occitan = 138

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Ojibwa = 139

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Oromo = 140

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Oriya = 141

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Ossetian = 142

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Panjabi_Punjabi = 143

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Pali = 144

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Pushto = 145

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Puyallup = 146

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Quechua = 147

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Romansh = 148

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Rundi = 149

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Romanian = 150

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Kinyarwanda = 151

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Samoan = 152

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Sanskrit = 153

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Sardinian = 154

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Sindhi = 155

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Northern_Sami = 156

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Sango = 157

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Sinhalese = 158

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Slovak = 159

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    American_Sign_Language = 160

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Slovenian = 161

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Shona = 162

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Albanian = 164

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Serbian = 165

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Swati = 166

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Sotho_Southern = 167

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Sundanese = 168

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Swedish = 169

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Swahili = 170

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Tagalog = 171

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Tamil = 172

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Telugu = 173

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Tajik = 174

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Thai = 175

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Tigrinya = 176

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Turkmen = 177

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Tswana = 178

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Tonga = 179

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Turkish = 180

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Tsonga = 181

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Tatar = 182

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Twi = 183

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Tahitian = 184

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Uighur = 185

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Ukrainian = 186

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Urdu = 187

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Uzbek = 188

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Venda = 189

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Volapük = 190

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Walloon = 191

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Wolof = 192

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Xhosa = 193

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Yakima = 194

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Yiddish = 195

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Yoruba = 196

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Zhuang = 197

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Zulu = 198

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Afar = 199

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Abkhazian = 200

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Avestan = 201

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Maay_Maay = 202

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Karen = 203

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Kiswahili = 204

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Alhanian = 205

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Bangla = 206

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Haitian_Creole = 207

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Laotian = 208

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Panjabi = 209

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Rwanda = 210

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Sign_Language = 211

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Serbo_Croatian = 212

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Tagolog = 213

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()> _
    Urvu = 214
End Enum
```

Comment: From [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3600867/1580288), it looks like string representations of the enum (as value attributes) is OK. But I don't know why the occasional nested "EnumerationValue" is happening.

Comment: Can you show the full Enum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WCF, enumerations are generally used by member names, not by the numerical enum value. You can force specific values through EnumMember(value:=""). Or you can specify

```
<servicecontract(),XMLSerializerFormat>
```

to use 'old' xml serializer.

The enum serializer tends to auto-complete the enum. Example:

```
<DataContract>
Public Enum TheEnum As Integer
<EnumMember>
  value_1 = 1
<EnumMember>
  value_2 = 2
<EnumMember>
  value_3_1  
<EnumMember>
  value_3_2  
<EnumMember>
  value_3_3  
<EnumMember>
  value_4 = 4
<EnumMember>
  value_5  
<EnumMember>
  value_0 = 0
End Enum
```

Will give you this values:

- value_1:   1
- value_2:   2
- value_3_1: 3
- value_3_2: 4
- value_3_3: 5
- value_4:   4
- value_5:   5
- value_0:   0

So we can say that these value nodes, are 'fillings the gaps' between explicit nodes' values. And, in these cases, max and '0' values, may be confussed it if they're on the top of the Enum. Only try this:

Put:

```
<System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
    LookUp = 9999

<System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()>  _
Unknown = 0
```

At the END of the Enum, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Just started a new service app with Visual Studio 2013 usig .Net 4.5 and I do not have your issue:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    TestEnum GetData(int value);
}


[DataContract]
public enum TestEnum
{
    [EnumMember]
    Test1 =1,

    [EnumMember]
    Test3 = 3,
}

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService1" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService1">
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
<xs:simpleType name="TestEnum">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:enumeration value="Test1">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:appinfo>
<EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">1</EnumerationValue>
</xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:enumeration>
<xs:enumeration value="Test3">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:appinfo>
<EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">3</EnumerationValue>
</xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:enumeration>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="TestEnum" nillable="true" type="tns:TestEnum"/>
</xs:schema>
```